# How to get CameraToWorldMatrix and ProjectionMatrix for HoloLens?

Tags: c#, camera, uwp, coordinate-transformation, hololens

I am using Unity to develop an app for HoloLens. In my app I need to process every video frame from the camera and render some objects at a specific location. For processing video frames I am using MediaFrameReference class from UWP. For render an object from pixel space to world space I need to get the ProjectionMatrix and CameraToWorldMatrix. But how can I do this using the GUID code from LocatableCamera https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/locatable_camera ? How CameraToWorldMatrix is calculated in PhotoCapture class?

Answer (score 1):

```
void OnCapturedPhotoToMemory(PhotoCaptureResult result, PhotoCaptureFrame frame)
{
  if(result.success)
   {
     ...
     Matrix4x4 cameraToWorldMatrix;
     frame.TryGetCameraToWorldMatrix(out cameraToWorldMatrix);
     Matrix4x4 projectionMatrix;
     frame.TryGetProjectionMatrix(out projectionMatrix);
     ...
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!